# An x86_64-linux-gnu-ld compiling on QT creator error. Cannot find -lGL

Tags: c++, qt

So, I've been running Qt Creator for awhile, and I've run into an error.

Awhile back I switched from an integrated GPU to an NVIDIA GPU. After this, I have been unable to compile any programs in Qt Creator. I always get the following error message:

```
/usr/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-ld: cannot find -lGL
```

I've tried a lot of solutions to supposedly "fix" this issue, but I have not been able to solve it.

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried reinstalling libgl1-mesa-dev?

Comment: Yes, I have. It still gives me the error I mentioned earlier. I just tried again, reinstalled, restarted, still the same error.

Comment: And what do you get if you execute `ldconfig -p | grep libGL\.so`? In my case it's:
    `libGL.so.1 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/nvidia-384/libGL.so.1`
    `libGL.so.1 (libc6) => /usr/lib32/nvidia-384/libGL.so.1`
    `libGL.so (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so`
    `libGL.so (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/nvidia-384/libGL.so`
    `libGL.so (libc6) => /usr/lib32/nvidia-384/libGL.so`

Comment: I get  libGL.so.1 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so.1 and then libGL.so.1 (libc6) =>/usr/lib/i386-linyx-gnu/libGL.so.1

Comment: It looks like the nvidia OpenGL libraries are not installed. If they were, you could try to modify a symlink to point to an nvidia's libGL.so for example here: `/usr/lib/libGL.so`

Comment: I don't quite know how to do that. Could you explain? I'm not new to programming and such, but I'm also not experienced

Comment: I'm not sure either. Can you try installing this one `libglu1-mesa-dev`?

Comment: It's already installed and in the newest version, but right now i'm downloading nvidia opengl drivers. Think that would work?

Comment: The last idea I have is to install/reinstall the GPU drivers. Which distro are you on?

Comment: I'm using Ubuntu MATE. I liked the layout of the menus and such.

Comment: Then try installing the proprietary nvidia drivers using "Software & Updates" -> "Additional Drivers" tab and choose NVIDIA binary driver. Another way would be to follow this link https://www.tecmint.com/install-nvidia-drivers-on-ubuntu/

Comment: When I attempt to switch to the binary driver, it kicks me back to the driver metapackage

Comment: If libgl is installed, are you certain that it's in your PATH? You can check if it's withing the Qt environment's path by going to _Projects -> Build Environment -> System Environment_ click details and look for the PATH variable. If the location of **libgl** isn't there then you must add it to your PATH.

Comment: The PATH variable is set to /home/ajax/Qt5.11.1/5.11.1/gcc_64/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin

Comment: Try add `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu` to your PATH or the location you installed the libgl library in.

Comment: I did that, and all I got was the same error. I'm going to try and rollback to a previous backup and try all of the above steps again

Comment: The error you're getting means that Qt is unable to find libgl on your system, based on your PATH, it seems you haven't set it yet or you set it incorrectly. After setting your PATH can you go into a terminal and paste the results of `$PATH`.

Comment: Yeah, apparently I did not set it correctly. I do go into project, build environment, and all of that, and it says in Qt itself that it is pointing to /usr/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu, but if I run the $PATH command, it does not say that. How do I change it properly?

Comment: In a terminal type `vim /etc/environment` and append the path of `libgl.so` to the PATH variable. The path of you `libgl` library can be entirely different from mine, so make sure you look for it. After which restart your Qt IDE just to be sure, and see if the PATH is updated. Make sure you add the library `-lgl` in your `.pro` file as well. You can read up more on setting your PATH [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/60218/how-to-add-a-directory-to-the-path)

Comment: I did that, and I confirmed that it was present in $PATH, yet it still didn't work. I don't know what to do at this point

Comment: And you confirmed that `libgl.so` is also present in the directory you added to your PATH?

Comment: Yes, it is in the PATH, guaranteed. I am still getting the error "/usr/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-ld: cannot find -lGL"

Comment: I figured it out, and I feel so dumb now. I created a folder called mesa and put the file libgl.so.1 in it, since libgl.so was linked to it or something. I've spent 8 hours, for that

Comment: Glad to hear it's working, these things happen sometimes.